# Security integration in hybrid mobile app

Tags: java, spring, cordova, ionic-framework

iRecently my app got hacked by using sql map.We added few filters to avoid unwanted requests but how to integrate security to the api calls, in back end my app communicates with  spring controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Well are you using any authentication on the requests made from the mobile?
Like JWT or a security token. You can check this [ionic](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/02/18/ionic-2-authentication-how-to-secure-your-mobile-app-with-jwt/) or [auth](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic).
Also make sure your making the api call your making it you can hide it many ways. Store it in a object and then call that object when your making the http or ng-resource request.